# AJAX vs ActiveX/Flash for browser-based game

Tags: ajax, flash, activex, cross-browser

I have been following the usage of JavaScript for the past few years, and with the release of extremely fast scripting engines (V8, SquirrelFish Extrene, TraceMonkey, etc.) the possibilities of JavaScript have increased dramatically. However, the usage share of Internet Explorer coupled with it's total lack of support for recent standards makes me want to drop a bomb on Microsoft's HQ, as it creates a huge amount of problems for any website.

The game will need to be pretty dynamic client-side, with animations and other eye-candy things, but not a full-blown game like those that run directly in the OS using DirectX or OpenGL. However, this might be a little stretch for JavaScript and will certainly feel extremely slow in Internet Explorer (given that the current IE engine can be hundreds of times slower than SFX; gotta see what IE9 will bring), would it be better to just do the whole thing in Flash? I know this means requiring the plug-in AND I have no experience whatsoever with Flash (other than browsing YouTube :P). It also means I can't just output directly from PHP, I would have to use XML or some other format to pass data to it (JSON is directly integrated in JS and PHP can deal with it easily).

Another idea would be to provide an alternative interface just for IE, though I don't know how (ActiveX maybe? or with Flash, then why not just provide it to all browsers) or totally not supporting it and requiring the use of other browsers, although this is plain stupid from a business perspective.

So here am I, wondering what approach to take and thus asking for your advice. How should I build the client-side? AJAX in all browsers, Flash in all browsers or a mix (AJAX for "modern" browsers and something else for the "grandpa": IE).

Comment: Internet Explorer is getting better. "Total lack of support for recent standards" is not an accurate statement and you're most likely jumping on the bash-IE bandwagon. I'm not saying that it doesn't have its problems and anomalies but IE8 and even IE7 aren't nearly as bad as IE6 was, and it helps if YOU follow good coding standards: use a DOCTYPE, use a reset CSS, etc. Many problems are solved just by those two practices.

Comment: @Ricket, I would like to point out SVG and <canvas> for starters. I would also like to point out that it treats XHTML under HTML compatibility in quirks mode. IE 7 and especially 8 are much better than IE6, but still lack a lot compared to other browsers.

Comment: IE9 is planned to fix SVG and HTML5 support (which should mean <canvas> but it seems unconfirmed) and pass the Acid3 test (hah, supposedly; Firefox doesn't even pass it and Chrome reaches 100 but not matching the reference image). Nonetheless I agree it's not perfect and I hope Microsoft is indeed revamping their IE team and taking it more seriously. I just wanted to make sure both sides were represented; I guess I was more playing devil's advocate, since I do exclusively use Chrome and FF.

Comment: IE9 looks extremely promising (especially the use of DirectWrite), though I'm skeptical in regards to standards compliance. However, even with IE9 I still can't make use of new features everywhere since there won't be a lot of people using it for a long time - heck, IE6 still has a big market share (*profanity*); this doesn't make me happy. (BTW, Chrome 5.0.342.8 beta achieves 100 with pixel-perfect rendering and smooth animation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend a plug-in platform (Flash, Silverlight, or Java) over AJAX. Having a clean layer of abstraction between your game and the client's browser is a big advantage. In any non-trivial AJAX game look forward to endless corner-cases where browsers differ in performance or implementation.

Personally, I think Flash is easy to learn if you are coming from AJAX experience. Flash is currently the most widely installed and proven plug-in for browser games. However, Silverlight and Java are both building momentum. Also, the Unity engine has become a popular choice for commercial browser games.

Comment: With a JS library (jQuery, maybe Dojo) I'm hoping to iron out most of the differences. Except for IE, I don't think there will be any differences with a library.

Comment: I don't have the experience to know for sure, but JQuery and Dojo have not been heavily use-tested on games so I would not expect them to handle game-related stuff well. If you go that route I suggest gameQuery. http://gamequery.onaluf.org/. The results in the demos are impressive, but this is by far the least proven approach, and as a rule of thumb, that means more problems for you.

Comment: I believe this answer is no longer valid considering the state of browser technologies today. And if the question were asked again today the accepted answer would be the opposite of the advice given here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't leave Java out of the equation. It's a powerful, fast language, and with Java applets, you can do almost anything. If you want hardware-accelerated graphics via OpenGL, [JOGL](http://kenai.com/projects/jogl/pages/Home) can do it, even in an applet.

On the other hand, it might not be right for you. But at this early stage, I think you should evaluate all of your options, and since you have no experience with Flash but sound like you've got a bit of programming experience, you might feel more at-home with Java.

Comment: Thing is I personally totally hate Java and will not ever touch it for a number of reasons (as a programming language). Also it requires the Java runtime, which is anything but small and fast to load.

Comment: To each their own, I'm not even going to try and convince you otherwise.

Comment: Also, an objective point: it's like shooting a fly with a bazooka, really big overkill for the needs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the current answer is Flash game.

Alternatives:

Java Applet: getting less and less common those days and it is not commonly installed as a plugin  on many computers.

SilverLight: too new and might vary and change in time. not commonly installed on many computers and it's Microsoft (whom tends to change technology every 2 years ...)

JavaScript / AJAX: Still a new kid on the block, it's on the rise it is true with many nice features, but still lack of good cross browser for IE even IE8, can not play sounds internally, still slower than the others, and you don't know where will it evolves.

Eventually probably the best solution for now is Flash development:
Cross platform. Works fast. Long time already alive and have a lot of support.

I hope this answer will change in the next year. Happy Peasach.

Comment: The only way you can say Java is getting less and less common, is if you're talking about Microsoft's piece-of-crap Java VM, which is thankfully not installed by default any more. It was to Java what IE is to the browser industry, but probably worse.

Comment: I think he means it's getting less common because Flash is catching up on all grounds (it's also got a higher install base) and modern browsers can do wonders with JS. Java is BIG, the runtime is BIGGER, but when high-performance portable applications are needed, it beats Flash and Silverlight hands down at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Jmonkey. The "plugin" loads if you have Java on your machine. Once it's cached, the next time the visitor goes to the page, it your game loads very quick. Check out their website for demos and see what I mean: http://www.jmonkeyengine.com/

Oh, I forgot to say, it's a 3D scenegraph Java engine. I just tried it again, and it loaded in linux. Looks they've put in some good work.

Don't do it with javascript in the browser. And Flash really can be a pain just because it's closed source and you don't know if you've made a mistake or found a bug - speaking from experience. I'd never want to make another Flash game again.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [RaphaelJs](http://raphaeljs.com/) , it is a Javascript library that make dinamyc images using SVG, and for IE, it try to make those images using the IE alternative: VML. Im using it on my own [WebGame](http://www.xhelos.com), but i dont really make complex graphics in it. The most complex thing done on RapahelJs was a heath map (20 * 20 tiles ) with a dinamyc opacity slider. An it work with jquery without any problem or configuration!